# Allow users to specify for how long they want the shared file to be accessed by external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, administrator

We revived a requirement to implement the following scenario:-

1. Contributor user shared a file with external user.
2. the contributor users can specify for how long they want the file to be shared.

Is this scenario supported in SharePoint and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set an expiration date for Anyone links. Please refer to following document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/best-practices-anonymous-sharing?view=o365-worldwide

You can take following steps to set custom expiration date
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes i know ,, but this will work for all the links, while i want the user who share the file to specify an expiry date,, so files will have different expiry dates.. thanks